# How to restrict normal users to run sudo commands only as normal users and normal groups

Tags: security, sudo

As the normal user `foobar` in group `users` I want to be able to run `sudo` commands as any other non-administrating user (e.g. `raboof:users`) provided that user `foobar` knows the run-as user's password. For example the following should be possible:

```
$ sudo -u raboof echo Hello World!
[sudo] Password for raboof:
$ sudo -g users echo Hello World!
$ sudo -u raboof -g users Hello World!
```

But `sudo` denies to run `echo Hello World!` in the case of the second and third variant above.

I configured the `sudo` standard plug-in `sudoers` as follows:

```
User_Alias USER_ADMIN = #0, %#0, %wheel
Runas_Alias RUNAS_ADMIN = #0, %#0, %wheel

User_Alias USER_USER = ALL, !USER_ADMIN
Runas_Alias RUNAS_USER = ALL, !RUNAS_ADMIN

Defaults:USER_USER targetpw

USER_ADMIN ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL

USER_USER ALL = (RUNAS_USER:RUNAS_USER) ALL
```

How must I configure the `sudo` plug-in `sudoers` to make it work the way I want to?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fumbling with the expressions of the above `Runas_Alias` definitions I came up with the following configuration that actually works for all three combinations of invoking `sudo` as non-administrating user (e.g. `raboof:users`):

```
User_Alias USER_USER = ALL, !#0, !%#0, !%wheel
Runas_Alias RUNAS_USER_USER = ALL, !#0, !%#0, !%wheel
Runas_Alias RUNAS_USER_GROUP = ALL, !#0, !wheel

Defaults:USER_USER targetpw

USER_USER ALL = (RUNAS_USER_USER:RUNAS_USER_GROUP) ALL

foobar $ sudo -u raboof id
uid=1000(raboof) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
foobar $ sudo -g users id
uid=1000(foobar) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
foobar $ sudo -u raboof -g users id
uid=1000(raboof) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

Nesting and negating the previously defined `Runas_Alias` definitions as follows didn't work for some unkown reason:

```
Runas_Alias RUNAS_ADMIN_USER = #0, %#0, %wheel
Runas_Alias RUNAS_ADMIN_GROUP = #0, wheel
Runas_Alias RUNAS_USER_USER = ALL, !RUNAS_ADMIN_USER
Runas_Alias RUNAS_USER_GROUP = ALL, !RUNAS_ADMIN_GROUP
```